# PHP array returns different value than expected

Tags: php

With the piece of PHP code I have been working on, I wanted to return only:

```
value1
value2
```

of an array.

However when I run this code, it returns the following:

```
value1
value2
value2
value2
value2
```

This is my code:

```
<?php
    $inputname = array("value1", "value2", "value3", "value4", "value5");
    foreach($inputname AS $i){
        if($i == "value1" || $i = "value2")
        {
            echo($i."<br />");
        }
    }
?>
```

Am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add extra `=` before `value2`:

```
if($i == "value1" || $i == "value2")
                        ^
```

otherwise you assign `value2` to every variable `$i` that is not `value1`.

Answer (score 1):

```
if($i == "value1" || $i = "value2")
```

Suppose to be

```
if($i == "value1" || $i == "value2")
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to set the `$i =` to `$i ==`

```
if($i == "value1" || $i == "value2")
```

//edit: to slow :c

Comment: Ah thanks, didn't expect that, I didn't even see that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if($i == "value1" || $i == "value2") instead of the if($i == "value1" || $i = "value2")